# Fail to catch errors with middleware

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

When my client hit the non-existing route, I'm getting the

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Error</title> </head> <body> <pre>Cannot POST /path/to/route</pre> </body> </html>
```

the `/path/to/route` is dynamic, of course.

I want to handle this(and other) error myself, so I could at least transfer it to JSON.
I've read the docs, searched the i-net and all I found was to set a middleware like so:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("err", err);
  console.log("req", req);
  console.log("res", res);
  console.log("next", next);
});
```

At the end/last `app.use`. I did, but I can't print any of the `console.log` above. What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is the case for the 404 error. When do you get a 404 error on "express"? When the request doesn't match your router address. So is this really a mistake? Logically yes, because in order for something to work in the express structure, the request must match our routers. But if it doesn't match, there is no error in the code. We have to create it ourselves.

For this:

```
// add this before your logic. Here we throwing not found error for example.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(new Error('NotFoundError'));
});


// your logging logic
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("err", err);
  console.log("req", req);
  console.log("res", res);
  console.log("next", next);
});


// Listen Port
app.listen(3000);
```